How to brew install rectangle-pro if rectangle is already installed?
I'd like to try out rectangle-pro as I've been a very happy user of rectangle (a window management app).
I tried installing with homebrew, per the tool's brew webpage, but it doesn't work, I get a misleading/wrong warning "Warning: Not upgrading rectangle-pro, the latest version is already installed":
$ brew install --cask rectangle-pro
==> Downloading https://formulae.brew.sh/api/cask.jws.json
################################################################# 100.0%
Warning: Not upgrading rectangle-pro, the latest version is already installed

Note: I already have rectangle installed via brew install --cask rectangle, but it still feels odd that brew tells me I have it already have rectangle-pro installed - I haven't! Is this intended brew behavior, or a bug? How do I install pro then? Uninstall rectangle first? Is there a way to not have to uninstall first?
This is what the brew website says for rectangle-pro:


Thanks for the rectangle tag. I reviewed all of the other posts and each one of them are missing key main tags like macOS and window-manager. Let’s use those and search for now.

A quick search suggests maybe try brew install --adopt rectangle-pro? Using the adopt flag, checks to see if the currently installed version of the app, is the same as what brew install --cask rectangle-pro command would have installed. If it fails that check, I think it will then overwrite the current app with the new brew install version of Rectangle-Pro. You could of course just download the dmg from the developers website and install it manually.

I had no problem installing both Rectangle and Rectangle Pro together via Homebrew, it installs two different applications into /Applications.
$ brew install --cask rectangle
==> Downloading https://formulae.brew.sh/api/cask.jws.json
==> Downloading https://github.com/rxhanson/Rectangle/releases/download/v0.82/Rectangle0.82.dmg
==> Installing Cask rectangle
==> Moving App 'Rectangle.app' to '/Applications/Rectangle.app'
  rectangle was successfully installed!
$ brew install --cask rectangle-pro
==> Downloading https://rectangleapp.com/pro/downloads/Rectangle%20Pro%203.0.30.dmg                                                                                                                        
==> Installing Cask rectangle-pro
==> Moving App 'Rectangle Pro.app' to '/Applications/Rectangle Pro.app'
  rectangle-pro was successfully installed!
$ shasum /Applications/Rectangle.app/Contents/MacOS/Rectangle
f62a0cc8f9dbcd406a8c3adec32898aed3a20dd7  /Applications/Rectangle.app/Contents/MacOS/Rectangle
$ shasum /Applications/Rectangle\ Pro.app/Contents/MacOS/Rectangle\ Pro 
f47647bfb9356a0aed344779026d221e66c27637  /Applications/Rectangle Pro.app/Contents/MacOS/Rectangle Pro

Maybe you already installed Rectangle Pro directly from the website? You can run
brew install --adopt rectangle-pro

to make Homebrew aware of this.

You can try this command:
brew reinstall --cask rectangle-pro

(The --cask option directs brew to treat all named arguments as casks.)
The reinstall option uninstalls and then reinstalls a package, as explained in the Homebrew documentation:

Uninstall and then reinstall a formula or cask using the same options
it was originally installed with, plus any appended options specific
to a formula.


Welcome to Ask Different. I've edited your answer to provide context for the reinstall command, but, as it stands, I suspect the solution proposed in your post won't work because rectangle-pro is, as per the OP's question, not installed. If you think the reinstall command could indeed help, could you provide more information on why that's the case?
